# Are there any modeling tools that help visualize how a 3NF model would look like against EAV?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, orm, entity-relationship, entity-attribute-value

Would like to find low-cost relational modeling tools that will allow me to map a logical model in third normal form to a physical model based on EAV. Got any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

EAV fails to conform to rules of relational normalization, therefore there can be no relational modeling tools that support it.

If your model is in 3NF, then there's no reason to model it in EAV.  Keep it in 3NF.